# What font is this in the picture?

Tags: fonts

I need information about the following font. From a first look I thought it is commercial, is it? Also what are math fonts that can fit well with it?

I appreciate your suggestions.

[image]

EDIT:

I see the following in Document Properties:

[image]

Comment: You can always look at the document properties via right click or check [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: Your second screenshot lists the embedded fonts alphabetically, starting with "AGaramond Regular". However, that's clearly not the main (serif) text font shown in the first screenshot. You should scroll down in the Document Properties window and see if you find a font named "Sabon" (or something similar). If the main font is indeed Sabon, you could look into using the very similar "Palatino". The reason I make this suggestion is that there are various Palatino-based font packages for both text and math. (In contrast, AFAICT there's no good math font family that matches Sabon Text perfectly.